# iPhone: How do you suspend the screen saver-fader to have an app run for an hour?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

iPhone:  How do you suspend the screen saver-fader to have an app run for an hour?
I need the app to be displaying info for an hour or more without the screen fading out to black.

Thanks

Comment: Sweet, I forgot about this setting in my app (it's necessary). Off to implement it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

But don't forget to re-enable the idle timer after an hour or you will just kill the battery of a forgotten device.

Answer (score 2):

The UIApplication class has an idleTimerDisabled property, just set that to false.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = TRUE;
```

Comment: @Nideo TRUE and YES are both defined to be one, so TRUE, YES, or 1 will work.

Answer (score 1):

`UIApplication *thisApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
thisApp.idleTimerDisabled = YES;`

Hope this helps!